# Plotting a curve fit with floats

Tags: python, parameters, curve-fitting

I am wanting to design a curve fit based on optimised parameter values, and have been trying to use the scipy documentation.

I have the following code and optimised values, which I am trying to align with an equation:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(boatman_temperature_function, min_temp, temp_range, bounds = (0, [1.0, 14.0, 34.0, 1.0, 0.5]))

array([1.00000000e+00, 1.82129682e+00, 2.65552803e+01, 8.57298246e-02, 1.15436890e-10])

def boatman_temperature_function(temp, max_growth_rate, min_temp, temp_range, skewness, kurtosis):
    num = temp - min_temp
    denom = temp_range - min_temp
    inside_sin = np.pi*((num/denom)**skewness)
    sin_result = np.sin(inside_sin) # TODO: numpy.sin input: radian? degree?
    final = max_growth_rate*(sin_result**kurtosis)
    return(final)
```

This is based on the following dataframe:

```
Temperature Growth rate Standard Error  Weight
```

0   14  0.363   0.110   9.091
1   18  0.677   0.043   23.256
2   22  0.822   0.044   22.727
3   26  0.936   0.073   13.699
4   30  0.897   0.051   19.608
5   34  0.000   0.000   0.000

However, when I try to plot the array, I receive a TypeError.

```
plt.plot(temp_range(boatman_temperature_function, temp_range, popt), 'g-', label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I'm a bit puzzled as to why that is, because even when I try to convert the 'Temperature' column to a float dtype, I still receive the TypeError. What am I doing wrong here?

I would be happy to send along my full notebook so far for complete context if it helps.

Comment: Try to provide a minimal complete code example that reproduces your  error. In the present form it is hard to say.

Comment: What's `temp_range`? Is it supposed to be _called_ like `temp_range(boatman_temperature_function, temp_range, popt)`?

Comment: temp_range is meant to talk about the maximum temperature. I was recommended to use temp_range instead of max_temp to make the curve fit process a bit easier. And yes, my initial thinking was to call temp_range as you described